# Is the baseurl support NFS shared repository for yum update

Tags: yum, nfs, base-url

I wanted to share a repository over NFS or CISF shared location. Is the baseurl support NFS repsoitiry. I tried something like below sample code.

```
name=XXXX
baseurl=//100.96.37.56/ShareFolder/1035
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
timeout=600
```

I tried to do yum clean, it shows error like: 
Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl = '//100.96.37.56/ShareFolder/1035'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be specifying the location in the following format;
`file:///path/to/local/repo`

Which would make your config file read as;

```
name=XXXX
baseurl=file:///100.96.37.56/ShareFolder/1035
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
timeout=600
```

More info can be found [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-configuring_yum_and_yum_repositories) on the RedHat site, or [here](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalRepos) on the CentOS wiki.

Comment: The above suggestion removes the error, but I am getting some new error as "file:///100.96.37.56/ShareFolder/1035/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /100.96.37.56/ShareFolder/1035/repodata/repomd.xml". This share is accessible by some username and password. How to provide this information.

Comment: @Prak I think you need to do that via `automount` [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/750497/fstab-entry-to-mount-nfs-with-password) may help